# mvc 3 page with pdf - scrollbars / loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf, scrollbar

We want to have a page with an embeded pdf file, and below a confirm button that the user has read the file.

With

```
<object name="pdf" id="pdf" data="@Url.Action("GetPDF", Model)" type="application/pdf" width="850" height="650" >
    alt:
        <p>not found</p>
</object>
```

the pdf is displayed.

A) In case the pdf cannot be loaded from server, can I disable the confirm button?

B) Can I check if the User has scrolled down the pdf to the end?

I fear I have no control over the pdf, but maybe there is a solution I didn't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check that the file exists using Ajax.

**1. Create a function to check the file exists**

```
function checkFileExists(){
    return $.ajax({
        url : @Url.Action("GetPDF", Model),
        type:'HEAD'
    });
}
```

**2. Use jQuery [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to check if the file exists and enable/disable your button accordingly.**

```
$(function(){
    checkFileExists().done(function() {
        $("#myButton").attr("disabled", false);
    }).fail(function() {
        $("#myButton").attr("disabled", true);    
    });
});
```

Check out [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) for more information

Comment: Ok, that is a solution to check if the document can be loaded / exists.